# Reject transaction at StoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

Apple suggest to use SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction) only when App provided functionality.
So, in case when transactionStatus == .purchased I’ sending request to my backend.
But what if I receive some fail (or networking fails)? I want to reject current transaction. But if I make SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction) I’ll complete transaction, which mean successful payment (but it’s not)

How I can reject transaction here?

Comment: If you can't complete the transaction, simply don't call `finishTransaction`. The transaction will still be in a pending state and will be presented to your observer again. From a user experience point of view I would suggest that you provide some feedback and give the user an opportunity to retry or inform them that they should use the "restore" button later to retry.

Answer (score 0):

**Method SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction) will just remove transaction from transaction queue, Not completing transaction.** It is correct way to remove transaction from transaction queue as it is failed & no longer required to do transaction operation.

You can also find same implementation approach in Apple storeKit sample code. You can check at file path: [iOSInAppPurchases/iOSInAppPurchases/StoreObserver.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc1991/Listings/iOSInAppPurchases_iOSInAppPurchases_StoreObserver_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014726-iOSInAppPurchases_iOSInAppPurchases_StoreObserver_m-DontLinkElementID_26)